# boto3 file uploading leaks anon inodes and causes 'Too many open files' error

Tags: python, django, linux, operating-system, boto3

I have python 3.8 script on ubuntu that uploads images to AWS S3 with consecutive calls `storage.save(path, f)` where storage is `S3Boto3Storage()`, path is s3 path and f is `BytesIO` containing image content

After each call I see increasing amount of opened anon inodes related to my process:

```
$ ls -l /proc/3036326/fd
total 0
lrwx------ 1 ubuntu ubuntu 64 Apr 27 13:55 0 -> /dev/pts/2
lrwx------ 1 ubuntu ubuntu 64 Apr 27 13:55 1 -> /dev/pts/2
lrwx------ 1 ubuntu ubuntu 64 Apr 27 13:55 10 -> 'socket:[158453777]'
lrwx------ 1 ubuntu ubuntu 64 Apr 27 13:55 11 -> 'socket:[158453778]'
lrwx------ 1 ubuntu ubuntu 64 Apr 27 13:55 12 -> 'socket:[158453779]'
lrwx------ 1 ubuntu ubuntu 64 Apr 27 13:55 13 -> 'socket:[158453789]'
lrwx------ 1 ubuntu ubuntu 64 Apr 27 13:55 14 -> 'socket:[158453795]'
lrwx------ 1 ubuntu ubuntu 64 Apr 27 13:55 15 -> 'socket:[158542709]'
lrwx------ 1 ubuntu ubuntu 64 Apr 27 14:23 16 -> 'anon_inode:[eventpoll]'
lrwx------ 1 ubuntu ubuntu 64 Apr 27 14:23 17 -> 'anon_inode:[eventpoll]'
lrwx------ 1 ubuntu ubuntu 64 Apr 27 14:23 18 -> 'anon_inode:[eventpoll]'
lrwx------ 1 ubuntu ubuntu 64 Apr 27 14:23 19 -> 'anon_inode:[eventpoll]'
lrwx------ 1 ubuntu ubuntu 64 Apr 27 13:55 2 -> /dev/pts/2
lrwx------ 1 ubuntu ubuntu 64 Apr 27 14:23 20 -> 'anon_inode:[eventpoll]'
lrwx------ 1 ubuntu ubuntu 64 Apr 27 14:23 21 -> 'anon_inode:[eventpoll]'
lrwx------ 1 ubuntu ubuntu 64 Apr 27 14:23 22 -> 'anon_inode:[eventpoll]'
lrwx------ 1 ubuntu ubuntu 64 Apr 27 14:23 23 -> 'anon_inode:[eventpoll]'
lrwx------ 1 ubuntu ubuntu 64 Apr 27 14:23 24 -> 'anon_inode:[eventpoll]'
lrwx------ 1 ubuntu ubuntu 64 Apr 27 14:23 25 -> 'anon_inode:[eventpoll]'
lrwx------ 1 ubuntu ubuntu 64 Apr 27 14:23 26 -> 'anon_inode:[eventpoll]'
lrwx------ 1 ubuntu ubuntu 64 Apr 27 14:23 27 -> 'anon_inode:[eventpoll]'
lrwx------ 1 ubuntu ubuntu 64 Apr 27 14:23 28 -> 'anon_inode:[eventpoll]'
lrwx------ 1 ubuntu ubuntu 64 Apr 27 14:23 29 -> 'anon_inode:[eventpoll]'
...
```

Eventually amount of opened anon inodes hits ulimit (1024) and I get `[Errno 24] Too many open files` for any operations involving socket/inode creation from current script.

The issue happened after upgrading bunch of pip packages. The problem is I don't know previous versions of these packages, so I don't know exact versions to which I should possibly downgrade.

Currently I have installed:

```
boto3==1.26.120
botocore==1.29.120
urllib3==1.26.15
```

I tried downgrading these 3 packages to boto3==1.26.36, botocore==1.29.36 and urllib3==1.26.13, but it didn't help.

I didn't try increasing ulimit, because I want to remove descriptor leak and not just hide it.

Comment: S3Boto3Storage is a django thing, not a boto3 thing.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to fix the problem by disabling threads for file uploading. Added this to settings.py:

```
AWS_S3_USE_THREADS = False
```